# MeteorJS TypeScript importing / exporting

Tags: node.js, typescript, meteor

I've been trying to get normal exports and imports to work on the client side of a Meteor application and for some reason the exports fail. VSCode has no complaints and can see the import result, however when I run the application, "test" is undefined.

**File 1 (features.ts)**

```
export const test = 5;
```

**File 2**

```
import { test } from './features';
console.log(`test ${typeof test}`, test);   // Outputs: test undefined – undefined
```

Is there anything special in Meteor that I need to setup for this to work? A normal Meteor / JS / BlazeJS application works fine. It's just while I'm converting the application to TypeScript where I've found imports aren't working.

I've also tried using require:

**File 1 (features.ts)**

```
const test = 5;
module.exports = {test};
```

**File 2**

```
const { test } = require('./features');
console.log(`test ${typeof test}`, test);   // Outputs: test undefined – undefined
```

The file is correctly placed as VSCode correctly picks it up:
[image]

Comment: Can you please check, if it works a) using `require` or b) using `import { test } from ./features.ts` ?

Comment: @Jankapunkt require gives me the same result. I've updated with the require attempt. Can't import with a ts extension as the file is converted to standard js on compile time. So after compile, .ts doesn't exist.

Comment: "Can't import with a ts extension as the file is converted to standard js on compile time. So after compile, .ts doesn't exist."

This statement doesn't make any sense as this shouldn't be the case with Meteor. You should be able to import with the extension.

Comment: Turns out it does want the .ts extension, which I'm now confused about as it then means it's not being compiled into js files at all. While it works, it shouldn't based on the way TypeScript is supposed to work. Annoyingly there's no Meteor documentation on this and it's behaviour.

Comment: It seems inconsistent as well. Files references with the full path work without the .ts extension (as it should), while files with a relative path need the .ts extension.

Comment: Of course Meteor compiles all TS to JS. It happens when Meteor builds for the target architecture. The error itself is raised during this step. How else you expect it to behave?

Comment: It makes sense now. The part that confused me was that we're hard coding the .ts extension which implies that once it's built it's still looking for a .ts file. Since it works, it's easy to assume that it's not compiled. When you think about it though, the hard coded extension would be changed to .js at compile time along with the 'import' statement.